# how to get projects from the asana ruby client

Tags: ruby, asana

I'm trying to use the [asana ruby gem](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana) to insert tasks into a project and I'm having trouble getting the project from the workspace

```
  workspace = client.workspaces.find_by_id(someId)
  projects = client.projects.find_by_workspace(workspace)
  #is there a way I can do something like workspace.projects.first() ?
```

Gives me an arguments error `find_by_workspace': wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) (ArgumentError)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API and all client libraries in turn will return actual objects when they are queried for. However, when referencing an object in the API you do so with just the object's ID.

Therefore, in your code above, `workspace` holds the actual workspace object. In order to use that in a query you must use `workspace: workspace.id`.

You can see a working example of `.find_by_workspace()` [here](https://github.com/Asana/ruby-asana/blob/master/examples/personal_access_token.rb):

```
puts "My Workspaces:"
client.workspaces.find_all.each do |workspace|
  puts "\t* #{workspace.name} - tags:"
  client.tags.find_by_workspace(workspace: workspace.id).each do |tag|
    puts "\t\t- #{tag.name}"
  end
end
```